# Django not installing in pipenv on Mac

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to install Django in pipenv, but it keeps giving me error messages

```
user@users-MacBook-Pro-2 \~ % cd Desktop
user@users-MacBook-Pro-2 Desktop % mkdir storefron
user@users-MacBook-Pro-2 Desktop % cd  storefron
user@users-MacBook-Pro-2 storefron % virtualenv  install django
zsh: command not found: virtualenv
user@users-MacBook-Pro-2 storefron % pipenv install django
zsh: command not found: pipenv
user@users-MacBook-Pro-2 storefron %
```

please any help here

```
user@users-MacBook-Pro-2 storefron % pipenv install django
zsh: command not found: pipenv
```

This was suppose to help install Django on the pip virtual environment in the storefron folder created. on the desktop

Answer (score 0):

First ensure pipenv is installed your machine, if not install it

```
sudo port install pipenv
```

While inside your storefron directory create and activate a virtual environment

```
pipenv shell
```

You can now install django

```
pipenv install django
```

Comment: When I try, it gives me this responds.  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/posixpath.py", line 380, in abspath
    cwd = os.getcwd()
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted

Comment: Seems like a permission issue with the OS, you can search on how to resolve the error after which the above steps will work.